# What is the difference between a Rain Bird SP40 sprinkler and Rain Bird 1800 series with the same nozzle?

Tags: sprinkler-system

Can someone please explain to me the difference between the Rain Bird SP40 sprinklers that already have a nozzle, and the 1800 series, which is spray only with the same nozzle type. Why would I use one over the other?

Thanks.

Comment: These seem like very specific models. Could you provide resources for reference, like images or web links?

Answer (score 2):

http://store.rainbird.com/contacts  I've already asked your question but thought I would give you this link to contact them yourself.  Be lots faster and you could give them details they need to be able to help.

Comment: Hi stormy! Do you mean you already asked the company the question? If so, might you want to add something they told you to this answer? That would be a way to help everyone. I get why it makes sense for the OP to call, but then this becomes more of a comment, and maybe should be posted that way instead of an answer. Thanks!

Comment: No, they have NOT contacted me.  I thought it would be better if the OP called them as he has ALL the information I do not.  Arghhhh, comment or answer??  Keep letting me know what I should have done, I'll get this straight one of these days...